# How to import everything from a module in react using es6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am using brace which is a npm module for theming in ace editor.
Currently, I am importing each theme using

```
import 'brace/theme/solarized_dark';
```

How do I import all the themes as I need to give the user the option to pick any theme.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create one `brace/themes/index.js` and export the things that you want to acess

```
export * as theme1 from './theme1';
export * as theme2 from './theme2';
....
```

Then import from that folder : (name is **index.js** so no need to give full path to the file)

```
import * as SolDark 'brace/themes'; // by default get index.js
```

Then you can access each method like :

```
SolDark.theme1;
SolDark.theme2;
```

Comment: I think you missed a `from` in `import * as SolDark 'brace/themes';` => `import * as SolDark from 'brace/themes';`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how does your file structure look like, but lets assume it is something like that

`|brace
 |---theme
 |   |---theme1
 |   |---theme2
 |   |   ...
 |   |---solarized_dark`

Then you could create `index.js` in the `theme` folder and inside it:

```
//index.js
export {default as theme1} from './theme1';
export {default as theme2} from './theme2';
```

assuming you have default exports.

Then in other files you just simply do:

```
//other_file.js
import {theme1, theme2} from 'someRelativePath/brace/theme/index'
```

or

```
import * as themes from 'someRelativePath/brace/theme/index'
```

Comment: Is there any other way I don't want to create files in the node_modules folder. Also is importing each file the only option in any situation.

Comment: You could create a file called, for example `themeUtils.js` and put it anywhere in your file structure, for example `src/utils`. In this file you do what in my example is done in the `index.js`. I don't believe there is a simplier way of importing everything at once if there is no such an export in the npm package.